# Opening a dialog with a list of all messaging apps. Pass phone number to selected app

Tags: android, android-intent

From a user contact card with name and phone number information, using an onClick I would like to open up a selection box, like the share box, that lists the available messaging apps such as WhatsApp, sms etc.

Something similar to the below code but I need to pass a phone number I think?

```
// Build the intent
Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+California");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);

// Verify it resolves
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mapIntent, 0);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

// Start an activity if it's safe
if (isIntentSafe) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Comment: I am using API level 21. I will check out shareaction now! Thanks

Comment: I don't want to "share with". I want to open a messaging application with a phone number so that it loads that contact to message

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SMS intent and then wrap that with an Intent from Intent.createChooser. By setting the type, it should show only sms/messaging apps.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
intent.putExtra("address", recipientPhoneNumber);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Messaging App"), 0);
```

Comment: That opens up the SMS application with the number in correctly but didn't give me a choice of messaging apps to pick from.